# Divs set to inline-block are overlapping and not moving to a vertical stack

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs that are pulled in using JQUERY

```css
div.box_spead_3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  background: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* float: left; */
}
div.box_spead_3 div.content {
  margin: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_spead_3">
  <div class="content property">
    <img src="/images/admin/icons/icon_property.png" alt="Property" class="icon">
    <h1><a href="#">Tower</a></h1>
    <h2>London</h2>
    <div class="seperator"></div>
    <div class="options">
      <img src="/images/admin/icons/icon_edit.png" class="property_edit" data-property-id="1" alt="Edit">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is that they expand to roughly a third of the container each but have a minimum width so that when that minimum is reached they go vertical.  The problem is that instead of going vertical they are overlapping each other on the horizontal.

Can anyone see why this might happen, if I set it to a fixed pixel width it works as planned but I don't want this functionality.

Comment: A jsFiddle would have been helpful

Comment: you could use flex, like so http://codepen.io/nakata/pen/JbPYjQ

Comment: Are you talking here about them stacking when the screen is resized down? E.g. using media queries?

Comment: Yeah, but at the minute I wasn't using media queries. I was hoping to just let the user resize down and let the browser adjust the boxes. Im now trying the flex option.

Comment: What is 'they'? `box_spread_3` or `content`?

Comment: Problem solved, I was setting the min-width on the content and not the containing box with the 33% width. All seems to be working as planned now. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/paulcredmond/pen/qqWbER

Comment: Yes that works well, if you can put it into an answer I can select it.